# Runnable jar file generated with java eclipse wont run when double clicked

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, applet, awt

I made a version of an 2D game by using an applet, java awt and some little java swing. I made a start-class containing a main method in order to export it as a runnable jar file.

The exporting works fine, without any problems.
But when its done and i try to double click the runnable jar file, nothing happens.

When I test it using the run button in eclipse everything works fine...

In the first moment I thought that my start-class may be the issue, but that's not the case. I tested it on an other applet, and there the runnable jar file using the same start-class works fine.

Now my question is: What could be the issue that prevents my runnable jar file from doing stuff when I double click it?

Comment: Run it from the command line using (something like) `java -jar the.jar` & note the output..

Comment: *"..by using an applet"* An applet is not suited to be a 'runnable jar' unless it is a hybrid application/applet.

Comment: it is a hybrid applet, since i made a startclass containing a main method, which executes the applet inside a JFrame. and that main should work fine.... i tested it with an other applet and there it worked fine.

Comment: So see my first comment. Something is different about this applet, and we can't know what without an exception stack-trace.

Comment: i tried to open it with the command line and it said "Error: unable to access jarfile MissileCommand.jar"

Comment: Are you in the directory that contains the Jar, when trying that command?

Comment: If not, you'll need to add the path to the Jar file, before the Jar file name.

Comment: BTW - 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: sooo, i tried it again, i had it in the wrong directory. now it threw me this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitiliazerError at Classes.startclass.main(Startclass.java:16) caused by: java.lang.illegalArgumentException: input == null! at javax.imageio.imageIO.read(Unknown Source) at Classes.Mainclass.<clinit>(Mainclass.java:90)                                                                                                   im using image IO to import images, may that be the issue?

Comment: well, i found the mistake now.... java eclipse seems to make no diffrence in whether stuff is written with caps or not.... but it makes a difference... it couldnt load my pictures, since the names of them were written with caps and i load them written without caps....

Comment: thanks for your help though :D

Comment: and im using applets cause i wanted to try them out. its not taught at my school and i wanted to try out something diffrent besides javafx which is the only thing used at my school

Comment: *"i found the mistake now"* Glad you got it solved! :) Now you might enter the correct answer below, or simply delete the question.

Comment: i gonna enter the correct answer below ^^ so others may find help from this :3

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake.

I've imported all the pictures i used in this game by using ImageIO.
I typed the names of the Images without a capital letter at the beginning, whilst the pictures in the folder actually had a capital letter. 
Java eclipse did not care about it and it worked when i tried it out, but when i tried to open it with the command line, it didnt work aswell as it didnt work with a normal doubleclick.

i hope this helps others who got the same issue ^^

Comment: so basically take care of capital letters at the beginning of the picture's names.

Comment: *"..gonna enter the correct answer.."* I was hoping that would be your decision. :)

Comment: well, if once the problem is found... why not helping others with it? ^^

Answer (score 0):

try right clicking on the file, select 'open with', 'Choose default program' and then select java Java(TM) Platform SE binary. If you don't see that option you should search for the javaw.exe in your java installation folder and select it. Also you should check Use the selected program to open this kind of file

Comment: first of all, thank you for your answer! well, java(TM) Platform SE binary is already chosen as default program.